# OpenLayers 3 - Source with multiple available projections

Tags: javascript, openlayers

Is there anyway to specify a (Tile)WMS source that supports multiple projections?

For example, my WMS server supports requests for both EPSG:4326 and EPSG:3395. So if the projection is supported in server-side, the tiles are requested with the appropriate projection, else OpenLayers tries to reproject one of the supported projections.